# Riak: 2i query not returning key

Tags: javascript, riak

I'm just testing out riak. I've set the backend to memory, given it 2GB max and enabled search.

I'm using nodejs and [simpleriak](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simpleriak). I've inserted 100 test objects with the following code:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 100; i++ ) {
    //add
    riak.put({
        bucket: 'testy',
        key: String(i),
        index: { a_bin: 'A' + i },
        index: { b_bin: 'B' + i },
        data: {
            A: "A" + i,
            B: "B" + i,
            C: "C" + i
        }
    }, function (err, reply) {
        console.log(err, reply);
    });
};
```

I can now successfully get my objects by key from the command line using:

`$ curl -v http://localhost:8098/buckets/testy/keys/1`

However, I cannot retrieve objects with my 2i:

`$ curl -v http://localhost:8098/buckets/testy/index/a_bin/A1`

returns

`{"keys":[]}`

Thoughts? Thanks!

Comment: I don't think JSON permits duplicate key names in an object, so `index: { a_bin: 'A' + i },index: { b_bin: 'B' + i },` isn't valid, and might be interpreted as the second value for `index` superseding the first.

Comment: That makes sense, but the documentation specifically states: "You can specify as many indexes as you like, the property name will be the index and its value the key."

Comment: Did you try adding them as separate properties of a single index object instead of conflicting index objects?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this, it appears that there's a problem with the simpleriak driver. I just added an object via the http api from the command line and then successfully called it with the index.